# Не работает скрипт проверки данных из бд PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Эта часть скрипта по идее должна из таблицы `users` искать пользователей у которых в столбце `role` указано `admin` и выводить эти данные в ассоциативный массив `$user_info`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `role` = 'admin'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
    $user_info = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_info[] = array_values($row);
    }
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['access_role'] = $user_info['role'];
```

А эта часть скрипта проверяет, имеет ли пользователь в столбце `role` значение `admin` и если да, то отображает указанную в скрипте кнопку, а если у пользователя нет в столбце `role` значение `admin`, то отображается надпись "Вы обычный пользователь"

```
if( $_SESSION['access_role'] == 'admin'){ // проверяем или пользователь админ
                   echo '<a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a>';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Вы обычный пользователь';
            }
```

При попытке вывода данных с помощью `print_r($user_info);`, выводит полностью все данные о пользователе:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => admin
            [2] => air_admin
            [3] => it@aircargosoft.ru
            [4] => a43cabd34541265a098842e2dddf5f74
            [5] => uploads/1611139080
            [6] => admin
        )
```

Структура таблицы `users`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема в том, что этот скрипт всегда выдаёт надпись "Вы обычный пользователь".
Не могу понять, в чём проблема

Answer (score 0):

Мда. Всё смешалось, люди, кони... Зачем вам загружать всех пользователей с ролью *admin*? Загрузите информацию о конкретном пользователе, который обращается к сайту и положите её в `$user_info` (в коде  ниже пропущены все необходимые проверки):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);
// тут нужно добавить bind данных и исполнение запроса
$user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);

$_SESSION['user'] = $user_info;
```

Ну а дальше проверяем пользователя

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного неправильно обрабатываете возвращаемый массив.
Если вам просто нужно чтобы ваш код заработал, замените последнюю строчку из первого куска кода на эту:

```
$_SESSION['access_role'] = $user_info[0][1];
```

Но вообще, ответ данный выше более корректный, лучше возьмите его на заметку.